# How to update SQL record directly from datagridview cell, without using textbox?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ssms

I have DataGridView with several columns.

[image]

What I want to do is to update the SQL table directly from datagridview.

For instance - I want to change *status* from the second row, without using an additional textbox.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this event CellEndEdit for your GridView and get the new value by Grid.CurrentRow.Cells[i].Value